# How to set scan angle in CObservation2DRangeScan?

Tags: c++, mobile-robot-toolkit

I'm trying to use mrpt slam algorithm. I would like to adapt the original "icp slam app" to use lidar scans from my simulation. If I understand correctly I should use the CObservation2DRangeScan class to contain the lidar observations.
My problem is that I cannot find how to set the scan angle. I presume that the scan has to be in polar coordinates, then if `setScanRange` sets the range in meters, how do I set the angle?
I cannot find a proper member function within the class, I am probably missing something.

A code sample so far:

```
    mrpt::obs::CObservation2DRangeScan::Ptr observation(new mrpt::obs::CObservation2DRangeScan);
    observation->resizeScan(i32NUM_POINTS);
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < i32NUM_POINTS; ++i)
    {
      observation->setScanRange(i, arrPoints[i].range);
      //here I must set the scan angle
      observation->setScanRangeValidity(i, true);
    }
```

mrpt version: 2.2.1

Thank you in advance

Massimo

Comment: Strange, reference manual doesn't mention release 2.2.1: http://mrpt.ual.es/reference/, either 2.2.0 or 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The angle is implicitly defined by the index of each range within the vector.
I just edited the [class docs](https://docs.mrpt.org/reference/latest/class_mrpt_obs_CObservation2DRangeScan.html#doxid-classmrpt-1-1obs-1-1-c-observation2-d-range-scan-1a9302f255c4aa4a14054cf43760a42eeb) to better explain this.

Note that this code describes the exact relationship between indices and angles:

```
float Ang = -0.5f * aperture;
float dA = aperture / (m_scan.size() - 1);
if (!rightToLeft)
{
 Ang = -Ang;
 dA = -dA;
}
return Ang + dA * idx;
```

Also: Note that the program [GridmapNavSimul](https://docs.mrpt.org/reference/latest/app_GridmapNavSimul.html) already allows you to draw a gridmap world, drive a robot and generate simulated datasets without coding a single line... ;-)